# A component is changing and it works but it throws error all the time in console

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I am getting this spesific error in this code

```
const [totalKm, setTotalKm] = useState<number>(0);
<TextInput
  style={{borderRadius: 10, textAlign: 'center', height: 50, width: 200}}
  mode="outlined"
  placeholder='Toplam Km'
  inputMode='decimal'
  value={totalKm.toString()}
  onChangeText={(text) => setTotalKm(text ? parseFloat(text.replace(',', '.')) : 0)}
/>
```

Tried asking chatgpt
Tried changin the input type to be controlled and not controlled

Comment: Please provide the actual error message, otherwise people will have difficulty resolving this for you.

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\gasperkmnative\node_modules\@expo\metro-runtime\build\error-overlay\LogBox.web.js:107 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

Comment: Your `inputMode` is decimal but you are giving a value that is a String. You should be passing in `totalKm`, not `totalKm.toString()`. Or, you can store `totalKm` as a String instead of a float, change `inputMode` to text, and pass in the value as only `totalKm` rather than passing in `totalKm.toString()`. Then just convert `totalKm` to a float when you need the float value of `totalKm`.

Comment: Well thank you for your suggestion but when i do that, it works fine in android but does not work on browser. Getting this error
component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component